# Firebase functions not logging "console.log()" statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've been struggling with the function below not having its `console.log()` statements show up in the Firebase logs.  If I take out everything starting with the `db.collection` call, the `console.log()` statements at the top will show up, but once I add that `db.collection` call, **none** of the `console.log()` statements show up in Firebase's logs.

I am not extremely familiar with JavaScript (I normally use Python for back-end programming), so this may be an issue with how Promises work.  I'm looking into this now.

Any idea what's going on?

```
exports.purchaseItem = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('data:')
  console.log(data)
  let lbcCustomerStripeToken = data.lbcCustomerStripeToken
  let lbcStoreId = data.lbcStoreId
  let amount = data.amount
  console.log('lbcCustomerStripeToken:')
  console.log(lbcCustomerStripeToken)
  console.log('lbcStoreId:')
  console.log(lbcStoreId)
  console.log('amount:')
  console.log(amount)

  let lbcFee = Math.round(amount * 0.02)

  db.collection('stores').doc(lbcStoreId).get().then(lbcStore => {
    if (!lbcStore.exists) {
      console.log('No such product!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', product.data());
    }
    console.log('storeInfo:')
    console.log(lbcStore.data())
    return {message: 'Success'}
  })    
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Comment: You may need to use the [stackdriver library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to return the promise returned by the asynchronous `get()` method, see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result) which indicates that "To return data after an asynchronous operation, return a promise. The data returned by the promise is sent back to the client."

So the following should work:

```
exports.purchaseItem = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('data:')
  console.log(data)
  let lbcCustomerStripeToken = data.lbcCustomerStripeToken
  let lbcStoreId = data.lbcStoreId
  let amount = data.amount
  console.log('lbcCustomerStripeToken:')
  console.log(lbcCustomerStripeToken)
  console.log('lbcStoreId:')
  console.log(lbcStoreId)
  console.log('amount:')
  console.log(amount)

  let lbcFee = Math.round(amount * 0.02)

  return db.collection('stores').doc(lbcStoreId).get().then(lbcStore => {
    if (!lbcStore.exists) {
      console.log('No such product!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', product.data());
    }
    console.log('storeInfo:')
    console.log(lbcStore.data())
    return {message: 'Success'}
  })    
  .catch((error) => {
    // To be adapted here, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Also, note that you should adapt your code for the error handling part, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors.

Finally, be sure that your `db` constant is defined with `admin.firestore();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the data that printed via `console.log()` in the specific function's `Log` tab in the Firebase console:

`https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<project-name>/functions/logs`

*Change `<project-name>` to yours (without `<` `>`).

*You may need to select specific function/log level to see the log in live.

Comment: The logs are not working and not shown in the logs of firebase platform

Comment: @KamelMili What do you see on the screen? What is the URL you’re trying access to?

Comment: Maybe you didn't pressed on the play icon on the right? it should show right away.

Comment: no, I pressed the play button, but it's always that way and the thing that I'm pretty mad about is the beta versions of firestore and firebase emulators. that I couldn't install due to java existence error and i do have java >_<

Comment: PS it worked the console but you should select function and info as type to see it

Comment: Oh, for me it selected automatically, I guess thats why I didn't thought about it. I'll edit and note that in the answer, you may upvote if it helped you in some way ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use view logs as it said in the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#viewing_logs

To view logs with the firebase tool

```
firebase functions:log
```

To view logs for a specific function

```
firebase functions:log --only <FUNCTION_NAME>
```